# MYSQL | SP | CURSOR - Fetch cursor into variable return null

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transactions

I want to:

1. Create temporary table.
2. Insert partial data into temporary table.
3. Run in Loop on temporary.user_id field.
4. Update each row after data manipulation and calculation.

The problem on step #3, i get user_id=NULL instead an integer from cursor.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE user_demo_sp()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE current_user INT;
  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT user_id FROM users_temp; -- Cursor on temp table 
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

-- Create a table
DROP temporary table if exists `users_temp` ;
CREATE temporary table `users_temp` (
user_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
aggregation_column INT(11) NOT NULL
);

-- Fill table
INSERT INTO users_temp SELECT user_id from users where condition ="condition";

  OPEN cur;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO current_user;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
   select current_user; -- Return NULL

  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur;

END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> you need to fill your temp table before declaring the cursor on it (just use nested Begin...END blocks):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE user_demo_sp()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE current_user INT;
   temp table 
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

-- Create a table
DROP temporary table if exists `users_temp` ;
CREATE temporary table `users_temp` (
user_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
aggregation_column INT(11) NOT NULL
);

-- Fill table
INSERT INTO users_temp SELECT user_id from users where condition ="condition";
  Begin
  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT user_id FROM users_temp; -- Cursor on
  OPEN cur;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO current_user;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
   select current_user; -- Return NULL

  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur;
  End;
END;
```

> Also in scenarios like this actually you don't need a temp table you
>   can declare the cursor on the select which you used to fill temptale

Comment: User still null, If i am changing the cursor to select from other table its works! i don't know if i can select from temporary table that i create after the cursor was assigned.

Comment: in this case you can to not use temp table, instead of it create the cursor for the select used to insert in temp table,