# MySql Fetch cursor into variable return null

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

The problem is that the FETCH INTO (in the loop) does not put the value into the variable. I've looked at [MYSQL | SP | CURSOR - Fetch cursor into variable return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28264471/mysql-sp-cursor-fetch-cursor-into-variable-return-null)  but the table is already populated.

The transaction table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `transactionentry` (
    `transactionid` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (`transactionid`),
    ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=651 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The stored procedure:

```
PROCEDURE `doTxnHouseKeeping`()
BEGIN
    -- Loop invariant
    DECLARE noEntries INTEGER DEFAULT FALSE;
    -- Error codes
    DECLARE code CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
    DECLARE msg TEXT;
    -- Txn vars
    DECLARE transactionId BIGINT(20);
    DECLARE lastTransactionId BIGINT(20) DEFAULT 0;
    -- testing
    DECLARE counter INT(11) DEFAULT 0;

    DEClARE txnEntryCur CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT 
            `transactionid`
        FROM 
            `transactionentry`
        LIMIT 1;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 
        NOT FOUND SET noEntries = TRUE;  

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR
        SQLEXCEPTION
            BEGIN
                GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
                code = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, msg = MESSAGE_TEXT;
                SELECT CONCAT('Error fetching transaction entries code: ', code, ' message: ', msg);
            END;

    OPEN txnEntryCur;

    mainLoop: LOOP
        FETCH 
            txnEntryCur 
        INTO 
            transactionId;

        IF noEntries THEN 
            LEAVE  mainLoop;
        END  IF;

        IF transactionId IS NOT NULL THEN
            INSERT INTO debugTable (`bigintval`) VALUES (transactionId);
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO debugTable (`strval`) VALUES ('transactionId is NULL');
        END IF;

        SET counter = counter + 1;
    END LOOP mainLoop;

    CLOSE txnEntryCur;

    SELECT CONCAT("Count: ", counter);        
END
```

Running the stored procedure returns this result:

```
+--------------------------+
|CONCAT("Count: ", counter)|
+--------------------------+
|                  Count: 1|
+--------------------------+
```

The result in the debug table is:

```
+------------+---------+-----------------------+
|iddebugTable|bigintval|                 strval|
+------------+---------+-----------------------+
|           1|     NULL|"transactionId is NULL"|
+------------+---------+-----------------------+
```

Which means that the value was not copied in

When running the SQL (as it is in the stored procedure), it returns:

```
+-------------+
|transactionid|
+-------------+
|          591|
+-------------+
```

Comment: additional reference (bug due local variable with same name of table column) from mysql bugs records https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28227 and mariadb bug report https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-30079

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the problem and it is weird. It doesn't cause any error and / or exceptions, just doesn't put any values into the variables.  The solution is to change the cursor declare statement from:

```
DECLARE txnEntryCur CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT 
        `transactionid`
    FROM 
        `transactionentry`
    LIMIT 1;
```

To:

```
DECLARE txnEntryCur CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT 
        `transactionentry`.`transactionid`
    FROM 
        `transactionentry`
    LIMIT 1;
```

Not even the documentation indicated that it might have been a problem (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-cursor.html)

I only fully qualify the SELECT (and WHERE) part of the SQL statement if I'm selecting from more than one table and thus never picked this up on more complex queries.

I hope this will save someone some time in the future.

Comment: I solved my problem using `table.field` instead only field name. Thanks !

Comment: What a dumb bug.  Spent an hour banging my head against this until finding your post... thanks!

Comment: Much obliged for sharing this. Strange bug testing my sanity for a while on this otherwise sunny Sunday morning where I should have been doing something more entertaining in the first place.

Comment: This bug appears on MariaDB 10.6.4 as well. i was going to spend all day if i didn't reach your post thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here:

```
DECLARE transactionId BIGINT(20);
```

You declare a variable named `transactionId` so when you do this:

```
DEClARE txnEntryCur CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT 
        `transactionid`
    FROM 
        `transactionentry`
    LIMIT 1;
```

Your cursor's select is picking up the variable you declared which is why fully qualifying the field works. However, if you don't want to fully qualify the field in your select you can rename your variable.

Comment: Thank you, much clearer answer than the older one from TungstenX below.  I had used a `products_id` variable name in my procedure, and then tried to `SELECT products_id` from a `CURSOR` into it, and couldn't figure out why I was getting NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the variable `transactionId` a default value

```
...
DECLARE transactionId BIGINT(20) DEFAULT 0
...
```

and also replace

```
DECLARE noEntries INTEGER DEFAULT FALSE;
```

with

```
DECLARE noEntries BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
```

since you want to use it as a `BOOLEAN` value and set it to `TRUE` later in the procedure.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Nope, didn't work, the entry in the debug table is now 0 (not NULL) but not the value of what the select statement returns, i.e. 591. The noEntries was a BOOLEAN but in the all the tweaking it ended up as an INT, even fixing that didn't help.